# How to access field search params in Helper file method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this method in my Helper file

```
def created_on_column(record)
  p params[:search]
end
```

when i tried to print `params[:search]`, but its printing it as `nil`.

Is there a way to access `params[:search]` variable in helper?

Comment: Please, do not overformat your posts. Extra empty lines in code and unnecessary bold text don't raise your chances to get help.

Comment: Are you trying to **print** params[:search]? Or to write it to HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're not trying to do debug printing here (and using `p` would be also wrong approach to this).

Maybe you need just this:

```
def created_on_column(record)
  params[:search]
end
```

This code will return value of `params[:search]` instead of printing it to stdout and returning `nil`.

Comment: I am trying access params[:search][:created_on] value.Its giving nil.

Comment: params contains {"utf8"=>"√", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"controllername", "action"=>"index"}

Comment: It should raise an error then, instead of returning nil. There's no 'search' key in params

Comment: Then how to access values entered in search box,even i am not able access those values in controller action using params[:search].

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, `params` are available to helpers. You can try:

```
def created_on_column(record)
  p request.parameters[:search]
end
```

or pass `params` when calling `created_on_column`

```
def created_on_column(record, params)
  p params[:search]
end
```

Comment: I tried your code,am getting this error ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):

Comment: Do you call created_on_column(record, **params**) in your view?

Comment: I am just accessing search params in helper.am not using any views.

Comment: Where do you call created_on_column from?